# Problem when using wait until in selenium py to wait for 4 new discord messages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, discord, css-selectors

I am trying to make my program click buttons on a bot and then wait until he responds with a message for each of these buttons clicked, then, I want to download the message content. The problem is with the waiting.

My solution was to find the current last message after clicking the buttons using a CSS selector and then calling a function to wait until that scans for messages and then checks if any of the last 4 messages is still the same as the initial last message. If that's the case, `false` is returned, and if not, `true`. This works initially, but sometimes the condition is not met, even though I know it was, monitoring the discord and it's not fixed by increasing the wait until time. There are some nonfatal errors being returned to the console, however, and I think they might have to do with the problem:

```
The initial_message_arrived condition was not met within 15 seconds.
The initial_message_arrived condition was not met within 15 seconds.
[34924:39452:0501/181506.352:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[34924:39452:0501/181506.364:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[34924:39452:0501/181547.797:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[34924:39452:0501/181547.813:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
```

This is my code:

```python
  lastMessages = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".message-2CShn3")
        lastMessage = lastMessages[-1]
        def initial_message_arrived(driver):
            newLastMessages = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".message-2CShn3")
            #wenn eins der letzten 4 noch das alte ist, keine 4 neue
            for i in range(-1,-5,-1):
                if(newLastMessages[i]==lastMessage):
                    return False
            #sonst returnt true
            return True
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(initial_message_arrived)
        except TimeoutException:
            print("The initial_message_arrived condition was not met within 15 seconds.")
```